# Is it acceptable to have an electrical box the same depth as the stud?

Tags: electrical

I have several "SuperBlue" electrical boxes.  These are very sturdy boxes and have the most room (cubic inches) possible without being *too* deep to fit in a stud space.

However my question is: If code says we must staple wire to the center of studs and drill holes in the center to avoid using metal nailing plates...what do I do when my box is literally 1/4" from being the same depth as my 2x4 interior walls?  We all know the wires enter at the very rear end of the electrical box, meaning I have wires well past that safety point of drywall screws at electrical box locations.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: "We all know the wires enter at the very rear end of the electrical box" *[citation needed]*. In the UK boxes often have knockouts for top, left, bottom, right and back entry. Not all box types have all knockouts, but if I wanted a particular knockout I could find a box that gave it to me.

Comment: I don't think the code addresses this. However, most receptacles are mounted only a foot or so off the floor. It's not likely folks will be hanging pictures/decorations that low on the wall, so the cables should be safe.  Switches might be in a bit more danger, but since they're typically near a doorway, they're probably mostly out of the way of danger.

Answer (score 2):

You may be misunderstanding the rules. They're not saying you can't exit a wire near a wall.  They're saying if you do, use a nail plate.

Comment: I get that.  But what does code say about boxes that are literally 1/4" within the back side of the stud? Acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is acceptable. If you think there's a particular danger to that one wire (cabinetry/trim going on the other side), you can always install a 4x6 nail plate over it.

Comment: So...basically use common sense when hanging drywall around the back side of these super deep boxes?  I'd rather not install nail plates over every interior wall receptacle.  I do not see anything in code talking about the wire entering the back of the box?  I found code talking about how much a box can be recessed...but nothing about backside clearance.

Comment: You are correct, on all those assumptions.